# Switched Firebase Crashlytics from CocoaPods to Swift Package now Simulator won't build on a M1 Mac

Tags: xcode, crashlytics

Just removed Crashlytics from the podfile, then added it as a Swift Package. Built for an actual device just fine. But when I switch to the Simulator, no go (and tried deleting Derived folders etc - no change).

Another dev using Xcode 13.2.1 on an Intel Mac can build for the Simulator just fine.

Doesn't matter if I delete DerivedFolder then build first for Simulaor or for device - when I get to Simulator it always fails same errors.

The `Excluded Architectures` for everything are `arm64`, `Build Active Architure=YES`

```
Xcode 13.4.1
Mac: Monterey 13.4

ld: warning: ignoring file .../Build/Products/Debugging-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCrashlytics.o, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
... (12 others)
ld: warning: ignoring file .../Build/Products/Debugging-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstallations.o, building for iOS Simulator-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRCrashlytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in <SomeFile>-8e51ce451b9a03f7582a9e76a8faf6a6.o
      objc-class-ref in <SomeFile>-e71967da3e8b662633c9220e635ffc51.o
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in SSLog-8e51ce451b9a03f7582a9e76a8faf6a6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: The pitfalls of early adoption. You may have better luck posting this as an issue on the Firebase GitHub if you haven’t already.

Comment: @fakegirlfriends early adoption? FB stopped issuing pod updates a year plus ago. Packages have been around for years. But yeah should go to the FB site. Geez.

Comment: I meant M1 with Simulator. And Firebase hasn't stopped supporting CocoaPods; `pod update` will get you the current Firebase version. Firebase recommends SPM after v8 but CocoaPods are still good.

Comment: @fakegirlfriends I'm not sure what the CocoaPods issue is, but doing `pod update` does not get me past release 8.xomething. Perhaps I need to direct the Podfile to use the GitHub site not the CocoaPods repository. In any case, SWP is a better long term solution due to direct linking of the code.

Comment: Posted directly to Firebase `Issues` on GitHub, will update here of a solution (if there is one).

Answer (score 1):

I posted to Firebase Issues but this issue didn't ring a bell. However, I did trip on an [Apple TN on M1 Mac build issues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon), and doing what they suggested revolved the issue.

It appears that when Xcode builds Packages the rules it follows may not use the target's build settings. I believe the issue was related to `Excluded Architectures`.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was fixed by making sure Xcode was running in Rosetta mode.

Comment: That would be a real hardship. I mean performance goes way down. But yeah, if nothing else works then slow better than not running. That said latest Xcode working pretty well.